# Posting multiple Arrays of objects from Javascript to MVC

Tags: arrays, json, asp.net-mvc-3, posting

I have found many answers for posting 1 array of objects to MVC, but I'm struggling with multiple. It's probably something small I'm missing.

This is my JS:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: encodeURI("<%:Url.Action("SaveSimulator")%>"),
                data: JSON.stringify({ 
                    gevelshapes: (gevelshapes), 
                    gevelgaten:(gevelgaten),
                    dakshapes:(dakshapes),
                    dakgaten:(dakgaten),
                    dakrandshapes:(dakrandshapes), 
                    dakrandgaten:(dakrandgaten) 
                }),
                success: function(data){
                    $("form").submit();
                },
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: "json"
            });
```

These are arrays containing objects with an x and y coordinate. Like so:

```
var gevelshapes = [{ x: "1", y: "2" },{ x: "2", y: "1" }];
```

My MVC controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveSimulator(List<Coordinaat> gevelshapes , List<Coordinaat> dakrandshapes, List<Coordinaat> dakshapes,List<Coordinaat> gevelgaten , List<Coordinaat> dakrandgaten, List<Coordinaat> dakgaten)
    {

        //do something 
    }
```

I am missing something because MVC thinks that `List<Coordinaat> gevelshapes` has 1 object with an empty x and y string instead of an array with 2 'coordinaat' objects.

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but mvc does not automatically parse Json string. Try like this:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: encodeURI("<%:Url.Action("SaveSimulator")%>"),
            data: { x : JSON.stringify({ 
                gevelshapes: (gevelshapes), 
                gevelgaten:(gevelgaten),
                dakshapes:(dakshapes),
                dakgaten:(dakgaten),
                dakrandshapes:(dakrandshapes), 
                dakrandgaten:(dakrandgaten) 
            }) },
            success: function(data){
                $("form").submit();
            },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json"
        });

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveSimulator(string x)
{
     var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     var result = serializer.Deserialize<object>(x); // You can cast to your preffered class
     // ...
}
```